# Derive from specialized generic types

Tags: delphi, generics, inheritance, delphi-2009

Is it possible to derive a class from a specialized generic type:

```
TGenericBase <T> = class
  // ...
end;

TSpecializedDerived = class (TGenericBase <String>)
  // ...
end;
```

Just wondering if this is possible at all...

**EDIT** Code works fine when I put it in a new project. Must be due to some other mistake; sorry about that

Comment: What happened when you typed that into Delphi and compiled?

Comment: I got an internal error at the end of the derived class. I'm not at work right now, but I will update the question tomorrow.

Comment: Okay, I extracted the relevant part in a new project and it compiles fine...I guess I have to apologize...the error must be somewhere else - although the compiler indiciates, that an internal error ocucrs at exactly that position...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  I do it all the time. It's very useful.  One of my favorite tricks goes something like this:

```
TSpecializedList = class(TObjectList<TMyType>)
public
 (extra methods specific to handling TMyType objects)
end;
```