# Is it possible to create a type alias to a generic record in Delphi

Tags: delphi, generics

I would like to define a record type (type alias) for a generic record. I would like to do this so users of unit b can have access to TMyGenericRecord without using unit a. I have units like this:

```
unit a;
interface
type
  TMyNormalRecord = record
    Item: Integer;
  end;
  TMyGenericRecord<T> = record
    Item: T;
  end;
implementation
end.

unit b;
interface
type
  TMyNormalRecord = a.TMyNormalRecord;  // works
  TMyGenericRecord<T> = a.TMyGenericRecord<T>; // E2508 type parameters not allowed on this type
implementation
end.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer to the question is that the language does not support generic type aliases.

The [only places where you can use generic parameters](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declaring_Generics) are:

1. Generic [class, interface, record and array types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declaring_Generics#Class.2C_Interface.2C_and_Record_Types), or
2. Generic [procedural types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declaring_Generics#Procedural_Types), or
3. Generic [methods](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declaring_Generics#Parameterized_Methods).

Comment: ok, thanks for answer. It is a pity. Probably for generic classes there is a solution (with some probems, but solution exists) [Is it possible to create a type alias to a generic class in Delphi](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/10060009/is-it-possible-to-create-a-type-alias-to-a-generic-class-in-delphi?rq=1)

Comment: @DanielAndrascik There's nothing there that I would call a solution. All I can see is code that makes things worse!  ;-)

Comment: does #3 work in Delphi 2007? I am trying the <T> works but I cannot use T as type of parameter

Comment: @SecretaryOfEducation Of course not, because that ancient version pre-dates generics

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thank you for response, can you please check my latest question maybe you can help me out.